# Are methods such as XContainer.Elements, XContainer.Nodes etc also considered Linq to XML query operators?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Book uses different terms for Linq-to-XML methods/properties defined in classes `XObject`, `XNode`, `XElement` etc ( such as `XContainer.Elements`, `XContainer.Nodes`, `XObject.Document` ... ) and for extension methods defined in `Extensions` class. For former it uses the term *methods*, while with extension methods it uses the term *query operators*.

Is there a particular reason why author uses two different terms or are `XContainer.Elements`, `XContainer.Nodes` etc also considered *Linq-to-XML query operators*?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which book you are refering to, but the Elements/Nodes/etc methods are considered Axis Methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387099.aspx). I would think the query operators would be things like Select/Where/OrderBy regardless of whether they exist directly on the type in question or if they were static extension methods.

Comment: Ah, so besides the semantic differences, the two method types are in every way considered "equal in the eyes of Linq-to-XML"?

Comment: Some of the "Query" methods are elevated in the compiler to participate in the from x in xs where x.y==z select x syntactic sugar. Also, if they decided to add native versions of Select/Where/etc. to XContainer the compiler would resolve to it instead of the extension method. Extension methods are syntactic sugar over static methods.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately I doubt that these terms are specified anywhere in a particularly definitive way - and I wouldn't worry too much about it.

I wouldn't be surprised to see the author using the terms inconsistently themselves. I'd be even less surprised if that were the case and the author turned out to be me ;)

Comment: Speaking personally, I completely concur with the second paragraph. ;-)